# How to declare when passing function as parameter to function template in .cpp file?

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to learn C++ myself by reading a book and do exercise from that book.

Now I am trying to declare an instance of function template inside the .cpp file. I know that I can declare/define that function template in header file, but I am still curious about how to do that inside the .cpp file.

Here is piece of code which is trivial but demonstrate my problem:

```
// temp_func.h
#ifndef GUARD_temp_func
#define GUARD_temp_func

#include <iostream>

using std::cout;    using std::endl;

int addone(int);
int addtwo(int);

template<typename F>
void call_adds(int, F);

#endif
```

Header file

```
// temp_func.cpp
#include "temp_func.h"

using std::cout;    using  std::endl;

int addone(int n)
{
    return n + 1;
}

int addtwo(int n)
{
    return n + 2;
}

template<typename F>
void call_adds(int n, F f)
{
    cout << f(n) << endl;
}
template void call_adds<addone>(int n, F addone);
```

.cpp file, and obviously the last line doesn't work.

**Edit:**
Based on solutions provided by n.m.

```
template<int F(int)>
void call_adds(int n)
{
    cout << F(n) << endl;
}
template void call_adds<addtwo>(int);
template void call_adds<addone>(int);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `call_ads` template requires a type parameter. `addone` is not a type, it's a function. You can specialize `call_adds` for a type like `int(int)`, but not for individual functions of that type.

You can create a function template with a non-type template parameter:

```
template <int F(int)>
void call_adds(int n)
{
    cout << F(n) << endl;
}
```

and specialize it:

```
template<> void call_adds<addtwo> (int n) { ... }
```

Note that `call_adds` doesn't have a regular function parameter any more, only a template parameter.

The compiler doesn't really care whether you declare something in a header file or in a source file, as long as the declaration is visible where is should be.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the answer. Allow me to confirm: because I can not pass `addone` as a type parameter, so if I don't want put definition of function template in header, I have to use a template parameter as the answer you proposed?

Comment: Also, I have to change the last line to `template` instead to `template<>` to make the code working.

Comment: After doing some reading, looks like you suggesting doing a template specialization. I don't think I need do that. I just need `Explicit instantiation` http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/1C75fSEw/.

Comment: Oh I see. Indeed I assumed you need specialization.

Comment: Mark as answer as it provide the idea of template parameter even though I don't need template specialization.